# converting java files into .jar and make it .dex

Tags: java, android, jar, dex2jar

I'm trying to edit an .apk file changing some variables or adding some functions in java files in it.

So, firstly, I used apktool to decompile the .apk.
Then, I used dex2jar to make classes.dex to classes.jar and used jd-gui for reading the file. As you know, the files in .jar were all .class files which are binary files and cannot readable, so I tried to convert .jar to java files using

```
'Save all sources'
```

in jd-gui, and it gives me the java files which are readable and editable, which are good for me. Then I edited java files and make them into .jar file using

```
'jar cf newjar.jar javafiles'
```

However the problem is,

jar2dex command with the new .jar file, the edited one always failed, and the reason is 'no classfiles specified'.

I think it's because I made it from .java files not .class files. So what should I do? Do I have to make all java files into .class files with javac command? Or any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java source code obtained from dex2jar and jd-gui is for reference only, it is incomplete and/or incorrect all the time. 
Besides, if it were completely reliable, there'd be no real need for Open Source.

As @Robert Williams said, you should look into smali if you're serious about apk modifications.
If you do, here's some links to get you started

http://smali.net16.net/

http://androidcracking.blogspot.in/search/label/smali

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java files and extracted resources, you should be able to import them into a regular Android project and build using standard build tools. Note though that decompilers aren't perfect, so the generated Java files may not even compile.

If you're serious about APK modification, I strongly suggest you look at [smali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali), which is a much more direct representation of the code, and can be compiled directly to dex format.